# No me genera efectos el archivo de css normalize para poder normalizar los estilos del navegador. ¿alguien sabría explicarme el porque? Adjunto codigo

Tags: css, html5

Adjunto img del codigo de normalize en donde utilizo la propiedad box-sizing: border-box y dejo en 0 margin y padding para poder comenzar de 0 a editar la pagina. Tambien adjunto el código en el que se visualiza mi html.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: al dar click derecho en el navegador de tu página, y darle "ver código fuente de la página" se ve tu css como lo llamas en el head?

Comment: si si, lo verifique...

Comment: No uses imágenes para pegar código o nadie podra ayudarte sin tener que esforzarse en reescribirlo todo a mano para sus pruebas y poder reproducir tu error. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas mejor aceptadas por la comunidad, gracias. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta quitando las imágenes y sustituyéndolas por su correspondiente texto.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.